# How to mark this message is not a spam?

Tags: spam-prevention, inbox-by-gmail

I use Google inbox for Gmail.

Sometimes Google think that message is spam, for example:

[image]

Which prevents to see images and click links.

But it's actually not spam.

I don't see any button to mark this message 'not spam'.

How I can do this?

Comment: question the same, but there is no real answer